# Batch File for "mclip" in Chapter 6 from Al Sweigart's "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" cannot be found by Windows Run

Tags: python, batch-file

Towards the end of Chapter 6 in Al Sweigart's "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" is a project called Multi-Clipboard Automatic Messages or "mclip"

I copied the following code and saved it as 'mclip.py' in a folder I created called Practice within the Lib folder installed with Python.exe:

```
#! python 3
#mclip.py - a multi-clipboard program
TEXT = {"agree": """Yes, I agree. That sounds fine to me.""", "busy": """Sorry, can we do this later this week or next week?""", "upsell": """Would you consider making this a monthly donation?"""}

import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  print("usage: python mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase text")
  sys.exit()

keyphrase = sys.argv[1] #first command line arg is the keyphrase

if keyphrase in TEXT:
  pyperclip.copy(TEXT[keyphrase])
  print('Text for ' + keyphrase + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
  print('There is no text for ' + keyphrase)
```

In the project is instructions to create a Batch file in a text editor with the following and save as 'mclip.bat' in the same folder:

```
@py.exe C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\practice\mclip.py %*
@pause
```

NOTE: User is actually my name in the script.

When I hit WIN + R and enter "mclip" in the window, I get a message that reads:

"Windows cannot find 'mclip'. Make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again."

The browse function of Windows Run works but kind of defeats the purpose of setting up the batch file accordingly.

Has anyone who read this book gotten it to work? What am I missing?

Comment: Interesting; I own a copy of this book and I can find no reference to "mclip" anywhere. That said, running `mclip.bat` from WIN+R without providing the full path won't work unless the script is in one of the folders listed in `%PATH%`. There should have been a line directing you to Appendix B with instructions for how to update that variable.

Comment: At a guess, try `@py.exe "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\practice\mclip.py" %*` - that is, `"quote the entire filename"`. If the name includes spaces, then `cmd` will see this as two separate parameters as presented. Another example of where critical information required to investigate the matter has been innocently obfuscated. Is `user` actually `%username%`, `FredBloggs` or `Fred Bloggs` ?

Comment: @SomethingDark: It's the first project in Chapter 6 actually titled: "Project: Multi-Clipboard Automatic Messages" 
See also here:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter6/#calibre_link-223

Comment: @Magoo tried adding double quotes but same result. *shrug*
I think the idea behind using WIN+R is that you're meant to add a keyword to the command line.

Comment: The second to last paragraph in that section reads `On Windows, you can create a batch file to run this program with the WIN-R Run window. (For more about batch files, see Appendix B.) Enter the following into the file editor and save the file as mclip.bat in the C:\Windows folder:` - emphasis on **C:\Windows folder**

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. This fix I found was to edit the Path variables:
Open the Start Search, type in “env”, and choose “Edit the system environment variables”:
Click the “Environment Variables…” button.
Under the “System Variables” section (the lower half), find the row with “Path” in the first column, and click edit.
The “Edit environment variable” UI will appear.
Click Add and type in the file path to the folder that contains your mclip.py and mclip.bat files. As far as I can tell both of these files need to be in the same folder for it to work.

Someone who knows more than me about how path variables work can chime in and correct me if I'm wrong.